# Display map after page navigation completes

Tags: flutter

In my app I navigation to a page with a fullscreen map. Currently I've implemented a FutureBuilder to render the map or else a progressindicator is displayed. From initState I request UserLocation (lastknown or current) and the maps navigates to the location. The issue is that the page navigation is not smooth after I added the map. I'm looking for a way to make the page complete its navigation before the map is rendered. I've searched but haven't found a working solution yet. Any good ideas on how to make this?

Happy Flutter day :)

Comment: currently testing RouteObserver and RouteAware

Comment: And RouteAware might not be the solution https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16547

Comment: Use Isolates to do any intensive work. An Isolates is essentially a new thread so that the main thread is freed up to continue doing UI work.

Comment: i would try with `new Future(() => initRequestLocation())`

Comment: This is my current way of getting position called from initState
Future<Position> _getPosition() async {    
      var position = await Geolocator().getLastKnownPosition();

      if(position == null)
      {
        position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
      }

      return position;  
  }

Comment: Not a beauty but it works. Map is still in early state.
I added a timer (debounce) in an override of didPush and it makes it work very well. Easy to replace in the future. When the timer debounce, I set a bool simply to make a delay of the navigation. Then the build uses a futurebuilder where a combination of this bool and the users locations is used in combination to display the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Isolates to do any intensive work. An Isolate is essentially a new thread so that the main thread is freed up to continue doing UI work.

from https://flutter.io/docs/resources/faq#how-do-i-write-parallel-andor-concurrent-apps-for-flutter

> How do I write parallel and/or concurrent apps for Flutter? Flutter
>   supports isolates. Isolates are separate heaps in Flutter’s VM, and
>   they are able to run in parallel (usually implemented as separate
>   threads). Isolates communicate by sending and receiving asynchronous
>   messages. Flutter does not currently have a shared-memory parallelism
>   solution, although we are evaluating solutions for this.
>
> Check out an [example of using isolates with Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/layers/services/isolate.dart).

Comment: Just did some readup on isolates. Also tested google maps which is the widget I'm using. I just did a default location, not getting user location. It seems like it's the rendering that takes up the time making the navigation non smooth.